# Mvc view operation result message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can the controller tell the view to display a particular message, if this message is not part of the model that the view takes as input?

For example, after doing an operation I display in the view the result of the operation, that is a "Message" field in the model. But if the model has no data after the operation, of course the message will not be displayed.

The model:

```
public class xxViewModel
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
    public string d{ get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In the view:

@Model.ElementAt(0).Message

The view offers the possibility to delete table rows; after deleting the last model element (table row) during execution, I would like to display a message, but of course it's not possible. Maybe I have to use something like session?

Comment: Add some code, which programming language, what exactly are you trying to do in particular?

Comment: Done. The programming language is C#.

Comment: Okay, i'm not really into c#, but i added c# tag for you, so your post is easier to find ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller set a ViewData / ViewBag property. Consume it in your view.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a view model containing you data and your message ? Like :

```
public class xxViewModel
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
    public string d{ get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<xxViewModel> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

Your view would look like :

```
@model myNamespace.MainViewModel

@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Message) // displaying your message

@foreach(xxViewModel elem in Model.Elements)
{
    // display what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to store this message for further use just to display it you can do something like this:

```
public class xxViewModel
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b{ get; set; }
    public string c{ get; set; }
    public string d{ get; set; }
}
```

And then the Controller goes like this:

```
public class Controller
{
    public ActionResult YourMethod()
    {
       // here you can set whatever message you want to display after the operation
        ViewData["Message"] = your message;
        return View(Model);
    }
}
```

And in your view you just call the message like this:

```
@model myNamespace.xxViewModel

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    // do some stuff
}

@Html.Label(ViewData["Message"].ToString())
```